# App works in emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, zxing, android-4.4-kitkat

The app I am developing works perfectly on my emulator, but it won't work on my phone when I try to debug it. I only get the message:

> Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse
>   Restart ADB integration and try again.
>   Waiting for process: com.deliciouslymad.tsukasa.critterbytes

It hangs there forever with no change on my phone. It doesn't work after restarting or cleaning the project, either. I've tried many solutions on this site already, but none of them have resolved this issue.

*-UPDATE-* 
ADB logs:

```
ddms: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:673)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:195)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:66)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:772)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

- The .apk installs on my phone just fine.
- I have 'USB debugging', 'allow mock locations', and 'verify apps over USB' turned on in my phone settings. Runtime is Dalvik and it's connected as a media device.
- My phone runs Android 4.4.4.
- If it helps, I am implementing the Zxing library into my code for barcode scanning.

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.deliciouslymad.tsukasa.critterbytes">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="ScannerActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here's my build.gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.deliciouslymad.tsukasa.critterbytes"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
}
```

Additionally, in my app's project structure, the 'Compile Sdk Version' is API 21 and the 'Build Tools Version' is 21.1.2. 'Source Compatibility' and 'Target Compatibility' are blank, and I'm not sure if anything is supposed to be there.

The gradle builds fine with no errors, but there is something strange; when I hover over 'getDefaultProguardFile' in the build.gradle file, it says that it cannot resolve the symbol.

I am a junior programmer and trying to learn, so please let me know if there's anything missing or anything I can improve! This is all a little overwhelming and I can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: maybe both is running together Emulator AND Phone?

Comment: They shouldn't be. I closed down my emulator, and I even restarted Android Studio before testing on my phone--just to be sure.

Comment: set your build target to your Phones Platform

Comment: I don´t think it´s a targetAPI problem...

Comment: did the app itself work normally?

Comment: The app works as it's supposed to in the emulator.

Comment: build an apk file and try installing it in your phone and try running the application.

Comment: I've already installed the apk file on my phone successfully. Also, I have set my build target to my phone's platform and I get the same result.

Comment: I just fiddled around a bit more, and this has shown up in my ADB logs:

Comment: ddms: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:673)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:195)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:66)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:772)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

Comment: Update the question with the log cat trace and the activity/fragment producing this.

Comment: restart your computer and try to debug your application